# Spring integration with Shindig

Tags: spring, osgi, apache-shindig

I have a Spring bean containing an interface, as part of an OSGI bundle.

I would like to use that bean in my Shindig project ( WAR). and inject it's implementation.

I tried to use Guice Spring integration in order to this, but no good.

What are my options to use OSGI bundle with @Autowire spring annotations,
inside my Shindig project?

Thank you,
Doron

Answer (score 0):

[Spring dm](http://www.springsource.org/osgi).

This will require some extra Spring OSGi config to publish/consume the spring beans as OSGi services, but you shouldn't have to change anything you already have done.